# Duplicate ObjectID in ArcSDE Table

Tags: arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, arcgis-engine

After making a check in from an arcpad AXF file, i notice that there's duplicate ObjectID records.

This ArcSDE PostgreSQL table is versioned and edited by Axf checkins and a .net engine application.

The weird behaviour is that the ObjectIDs from checkin start from the last ObjectID checked in from AXF in the last time, but between these times i added several records using the .net app so the ObjectIDs produced here are duplicated by the last check in, the .net app adds record directly through PostgreSQL, so i set the ObjectID  to (Max(ObjectID) + 1).

i'm using ArcSDE 10.1 and PostgreSQL 9.0.8.

i'm not sure but i suppose that the problem comes from generating ObjectID in .net app level.

How could I generate an ObjectID and inform ArcSDE that this ObjectID has been used ?

Comment: Would it be helpful to add a [Global Unique Identifier](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000014000000) (GUID)?

Comment: i avoided GUID because it's much harder to generate GUID to insert row from .net app, using pgsql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions for your problem:

1) Modify the ArcSDE System tables from your .NET application.  The `SDE_LAYERS` and `SDE_TABLE_REGISTRY` tables contain rows that represent your table.  The row for your table has a `MINIMUM_ID` field value, which is what the geodatabase will use when it inserts new rows.

I don't recommend making changes to the ArcSDE tables, as they are used by the geodatabase.  It is risky.

2) Alter your table's registration with the [sdetable](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/support_files/datamgmt/sdetable.htm) command so that the geodatabase does not assign IDs automatically.  This is the `-C USER` option.  Then, create a sequence in your database that assigns unique integer IDs to new rows.

I prefer this method as it ensure that a single entity (the database) is now responsible for assigning IDs, and both ArcSDE and your code will need to worry about it.

Comment: i'm a newbie in Arcsde, i tried the commands, but it seems that i'm missing something, it seems i don't have a service, 
how to make it ?
C:\Users\hp>sdeservice -o list

SDE service Information
------------------------------------------------------------------
Sde service  doesn't exist or is not registered properly.